# Protractor Console.Log export options?

Tags: csv, protractor

Is it possible to divert the output of `console.log` to some sort of export file? CSV for example?

Comment: What our talking about is a log. There are numerous loggers available for nodeJs so I would advise searching for that term. [Here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/intermediate/how-to-log/) is an article to get you started

Comment: *What you are * I meant to say